# try Parse Json in Android, get arraylist exception

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a json like this:

```
[{"campaignName":"2012 Q1","id":1,"source":"Added by subject","status":"Draft","subject":"Test Subject1"},{"campaignName":"2012 Q2","id":2,"source":"Added by reviewer","status":"Created","subject":"Test Subject2"},{"campaignName":"2012 Q2","id":3,"source":"Added by reviewer","status":"Created","subject":"Test Subject62"}]
```

I have classes:

```
public class Json_ToDoData {
private ArrayList<ToDo> mList;

public Json_ToDoData() {

}

public ArrayList<ToDo> getmList() {
    return mList;
}

public void setmList(ArrayList<ToDo> mList) {
    this.mList = mList;
}
```

}

and: `public class ToDo {
    public ToDo() {
    }

```
@SerializedName("campaignName")
private String campaignName;

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("source")
private String source;

@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

@SerializedName("subject")
private String subject; ... gettes and settes ...}`
```

I always get an excepiton:

> 10-08 15:17:46.600: W/System.err(2557): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
>   and I do not understand why. here is my line to parse:

```
            Json_ToDoData rr = new JSONDeserializer<Json_ToDoData>().deserialize(sb.toString(), Json_ToDoData.class);
```

Please help on me, thx

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that user json string is not in proper format.
Try to format your json string in below format:

```
{ 
    jsonObjectName: 
    [ 
          { 
             "campaignName":"2012 Q1", 
             "id":1,
             "source":"Added by subject",
             "status":"Draft",
             "subject":"Test Subject1"
          } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: btw he can add them on runtime before start parsing.

Answer (score 0):

in your json string;
value of "id" is defined as Integer and you are trying to parse it into string,
i think that's the root cause of the exception...

in Todo class, it is defined as;

```
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
```

but in json string it is defined as;

```
"id":1
```

to fix that, either you can update field in your class to

```
@SerializedName("id")
private Integer id;
```

or in your json string to

```
"id":"1"
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to say thank you for you cooperate in this question, the soulution was about my parser, I mean I had changed the code for the following:

```
        JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(sb.toString());
        JSONArray rootArray = (JSONArray) jsonTokener.nextValue();
        rootArray.toString();
```